# How to set the ViewModel value from jquery in MVC Rozor view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Below is my ViewModel

```
public class MenuViewModel
    {
        public bool IsEdit { get; set; }
    }
```

On click of edit button I want to set IsEdit to true using jquery.

```
$("#custom-menu #edit").click(function (e) {
                $('#panel-create #@Html.NameFor(model => model.IsEdit)').val(true);
            });
```

I tried this. But no luck.

Comment: Show you view code for property `IsEdit` (are you generating a checkbox?)

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a check box then you can simply select that checkbox by name.
for example

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="IsValid" /> 
   <input type="button" id="abc" value="click"/>

   <script>
   $('#abc').click(function(){
   $("input[name=IsValid]").prop("checked", true);
   });

   </script>
```